# Open Eclipse view programmatically in plugin-project

Tags: java, plugins, view, eclipse-plugin

I want to open the view "Package Explorer" after a special event, inside my Eclipse plugin application.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("viewId");
```

But what is the `id` od the package explorer view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id is `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer` for the JDT Package Explorer.

You can determine any ID if you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> while in the view. e.g. you get this pop-up (if you have PDE installed). See [Vogella's tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy) for more info on using the Spy.

[image]